# What was used to create HubSpot's and Saleforce's app stores?

Tags: web-applications, app-store, e-commerce, marketplace

Does anybody know what solution HubSpot or Saleforce used to create their app stores, or if they wrote it themselves from scratch?

HubSpot's: https://app.hubspot.com/market/front/list
Salesforce's: http://appexchange.salesforce.com/

They look rather similar, so I have a hunch that they are built on a common platform, but I don't see any evidence of that in the source code. If they did build them from scratch, does anybody know of a potential whitelabel solution that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

HubSpot Marketplace is built on java back-end platform and the front end is a generic web framework. I do not know what Salesforce platform is built on. 
I also do not know of any open source frontend or backend marketplace platforms. They are usually tightly integrated to the company product so it is probably not worth making generic.

Comment: Thanks @newtonik! Out of curiousity, how do you know how the HubSpot Marketplace was developed?